# jws.sign is not working with algorithm RS256

Tags: python, jwt, encode, jose

I am trying to sign a JSON encoded object with jws.sign and hence tried this example given here:
https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jws/index.html

But problem is that jws.sign is working fine with algorithm HS256 given in the example above but fails with algorithm RS256 with this error:

> > > signed = jws.sign({'a': 'b'}, 'secret', algorithm='RS256')
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jose/backends/cryptography_backend.py", line 231, in **init**
> > > self.prepared_key = load_pem_public_key(key, self.cryptography_backend())
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 23, in load_pem_public_key
> > > return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1273, in load_pem_public_key
> > > self._handle_key_loading_error()
> > > File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1526, in _handle_key_loading_error
> > > raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.")
> > > ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.

Any leads will be helpful

Comment: 'secret' is not a valid RS256 key. You need a proper RS256 private key to sign, and a matching public key to verify.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation as you were, for several days, after a lot of searching I finally understood what the problem was and I came up with the solution below. Let me explain.

1. **Example that WILL NOT work**

> ```
> from jose import jws
> signed = jws.sign({'a': 'b'}, 'secret', algorithm='RS256')
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> `jose.exceptions.JWSError: Could not deserialize key data.`

2. **Issues**

   The 'secret' used as a key is applicable for HS256 algorithm, however, it is **not applicable** for **RS256** algorithm.
3. **Improvements needed**

   - Go to a RSA Key Generator website such as: https://cryptotools.net/rsagen and generate a key. *(Retain default settings on the website.)*
   - Copy the Private and Public Keys into separate variables in your code. We need  the Public Key to verify.
   - **Note:** Retain the newlines AFTER `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and BEFORE `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. **They are a must, if you miss them then you will again get the deserialize error.**

[image: Generating a new RSA Private Key.]

4. **Working Example**

> ```
> from jose import jws
>
> private_key = '''
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> MIICWwIBAAKBgQCUn8GgYNd49UCmHZl0cmbHQucMJEPZQoCzisBZ3D80jlhea6di
> dPrPHNhb9JNNOY2W4Ip6AfggbpFeemUhPhD88yz8Y9ntNzH0ztEC6JV5lSyhOKLn
> f+pccfXvHwakXXIRpHKoCqIUPDKtiyo6S9zjfihkHkh+jDY7dgvaQJAvkQIDAQAB
> AoGAdUiAntPtFbnME4qGH1tr+dC0zWMM27TcJVLYKdFhW1L9Lz2a8FpJ1gj4P9CI
> MUe6kRaOkGtfaBB4zOqfRZVaB13OMSn3JnXeP4VpzFpFYKJCeKfrnbiIFMqzarfg
> Kk8FSVHxSs3pZQtLhmUxx1CfjOUgIj0UKhfnhyLmh4zc80ECQQDUglcCfssFioVe
> PSWOoi6LXwGxky2StoiUg/AH6RDtDZDhJi5pHgwtPWJkqvKTmoJvgp8A7Qvn8eCl
> 5A2xuN3JAkEAswpiamr8gme09Z9f5dbTd62fKMq+n5eVa/C9Uqt1FGTCOcjELp6z
> z4km7rgz7DNS1R0E3q2Y8c5SRvPbNokHiQJAaKeD2Cu/Kgxs39s3KsY+K87vE5eK
> wwz3uEQ9qneiKUwcBHV8N7JfhswLL85sRjq6b9YhHiCfU2vwGWJ1SAfl2QJAA40t
> Lpc4sw2DlWu350M/ppwXECQVa+0B1cZMuxsTk3f8MlE9Mv+K6Y766rlUrlbGSdvt
> gM1Iv2MsVqP3sTk+oQJABkHcGx+31fcKJoWgx+yjMuN2eo13hQD/Ie4hUXnM6nF2
> vzqiaNCgAA4udqFRVGjqa5Lb8rdbALFzja2fuSH4eQ==
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> '''
> signed = jws.sign({'name': 'Jai Seeta Ram'}, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
>
> print("Output 1:", signed)
>
> public_key = '''
> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUn8GgYNd49UCmHZl0cmbHQucM
> JEPZQoCzisBZ3D80jlhea6didPrPHNhb9JNNOY2W4Ip6AfggbpFeemUhPhD88yz8
> Y9ntNzH0ztEC6JV5lSyhOKLnf+pccfXvHwakXXIRpHKoCqIUPDKtiyo6S9zjfihk
> Hkh+jDY7dgvaQJAvkQIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
> '''
> print("Output 2: ", jws.verify(signed, public_key, algorithms='RS256'))
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Output 1: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSmFpIFNlZXRhIFJhbSJ9.aEEq-ZBA88DL96XO5rLunRUIhd3zCtb1r0ItPnP1d2yKFJ4agkykzYvHVvHa1muKUPwi9HEbxvKf4GXHtl2VF_xOJPJUsRfTGYbMwsrZ1KomdDmdEtiqEa-59spXAGMUCpFXNED7pChnHeNGEaxiOXqa_N7zqIf1NEV75ku_83w
> Output 2:  b'{"name":"Jai Seeta Ram"}'
> ```